# How to change UIDocumentInteractionController Done button text and background color

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

How to change the background color and text color of done button? Is there a way that I can change the navigationbar color and navigation bar title color and bottom bar color also? Attached screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot

Comment: I am able to see the attached screenshot. Is it not visible to you? Do I need to upload it again?

Comment: I can see it now, just now it said 'imgur is over capacity'

Comment: @Dee: Have you solved it yet? I have the same problem. I set BarTintColor, but it seem not effect.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Here is the code working for me perfectly:

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightBold)]
    return self
}
```

Comment: Works fine but don't forget to set back to whatever you had before! I do this in the "viewWillAppear" in the view that presented the preview.

Comment: I have a lot of customization in AppDelegate.swift. To get correct colors in the preview window (and all subviews) I had to remove this in AppDelegate: window?.tintColor = x

And add this to the above list:

UILabel.appearance().textColor = CommonColors.appleTint
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = CommonColors.appleTint

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hacky as its relying on the fact that QLPreviewController is the class implementing the UIDocumentInteractionController but something like this is the least intrusive solution.  Do it before you display the UIDocumentInteractionController

```
import QuickLook

UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf [QLPreviewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: For Swift 4: UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.black

It works for the preview but how to change the tint color of "OpenInMenu" footer when sharing the file (pressing sharing button in the preview view)? Same as docController.presentOpenInMenu.

Answer (score 1):

I have a idear to change the bar color:

```
let allNavigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
allNavigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red  // change the bar background color
allNavigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black // change the Done button's tintColor

let alloolbar = UIToolbar.appearance()
allToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.red  // dones't work, try backgroundImage
allToolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // dones't work
allToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.brown // change the toolbar's item tint color
```

but this method has a great effect，all your `UINavigationBar`and `UIToolBar` will make that change.

Hope anyone else can give a better solusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tint color of the window temporally.

```
func presentDocument() {
    //present the controller here
    self.appDelegate.window.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Then change it back later:

```
func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(documentInteractionController) { //replace parameter with your uidocumentviewinteractioncontroller
    self.appDelegate.window.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dee. I guess you have asked this part in one of your other question. In that case you were not able to show that preview controller. In that question suggested answer is to return "self" from that delegate method. If you implement that correctly then your preview will use same navigation bar colour as its parent controller is using. I mean if you have opened UIDocumentInteractionController directly from some ViewController then UIDocumentInteractionController will use its parent viewController's navigation bar colour. This may help you to change Done button colour

Comment: I am able to modify the navigationbar button title and text and background color now. but the bottom toolbar color is not working. Could you please help me with that

Comment: @Dee I am unable to modify the navigationbar button title and text and background color. How you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : (You need to implement UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate)

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self.navigationController ?? self
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     let QLNavAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self])
    QLNavAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.red // some
    QLNavAppearance.barTintColor =  UIColor.red // some
    QLNavAppearance.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red // some
```